# EPEL Repo GPG Key Working?

Tags: centos, redhat, gpg, epel

I followed the below steps to grab the EPEL GPG key and I'm trying to verify if it's working. This is on a freshly installed RHEL7 system.

Repo: https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/

```
# cd /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/
# wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7
# cd /etc/yum.repos.d
```

Edit: /etc/yum.repos.d/dl.fedoraproject.org_pub_epel_7_x86_64_.repo

```
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7
```

I do a test install with the `python-pip` package and it shows that it's installing with my EPEL repo:

```
Installing:
python-pip       noarch       7.1.0-1.el7      dl.fedoraproject.org_pub_epel_7_x86_64_         1.5 M

Transaction Summary

Install  1 Package

Total download size: 1.5 M
Installed size: 6.6 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
python-pip-7.1.0-1.el7.noarch.rpm                    1.5 MB  00:00:01
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
Installing : python-pip-7.1.0-1.el7.noarch                        1/1
Verifying  : python-pip-7.1.0-1.el7.noarch                        1/1

Installed:
python-pip.noarch 0:7.1.0-1.el7

Complete!
```

This is all I get. I was led to believe that it prompts to confirm the keys,e.g., `Retreiving key from file:///..etc..., Importing GPG key 0x35....`. It never mentions anything about a GPG key/signature so I'm not sure if it's working. Any help on this would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check if yum is configured to check gpg signatures.  You're looking for something like this in `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo`:

```
[epel]
 [...]
gpgcheck=1
```

If that's there, then as Alex notes, you wouldn't be able to use the repo if the signatures weren't matching the keys.  That is also [Red Hat's formal advice](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sect-Security_Guide-Updating_Packages-Verifying_Signed_Packages.html) on the subject (see bottom of linked page).

Comment: Thanks, MaddHatter. The gpgcheck is set to 1 in the .repo file. I'll keep poking away at this.

Comment: If you're satisfied, you should accept one of the answers to this question, by clicking the tick outline next to it.  My apologies if you already know this.

Comment: I'm training for an exam so I was using a lab server. I did a local install with CentOS 7 and I was able to solve my question. After recently adding a GPG key it will verify if you want to use it the first time. Thanks all.

Comment: To be precise, after you put a key on disc, `yum` will ask if you want to import it to the keyring when it next comes across it.

Answer (score 0):

If it wasn't working, you wouldn't be able to use epel repo, as simple as that.